# how to attach properties to vertices in a graphx and retrieve the neighbourhood

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am rather new with Spark and Scala... I have a graph:Graph[Int, String] and I'd like to attach to these vertices some properties I have in a DataFrame.

What I need to do is, for each vertex, to find the average value in the neighbourhood for each property. This is my approach so far, but I don't understand how to correctly map the Row I get from the join of the two data frames:

```
val res = graph.collectNeighbors(EdgeDirection.Either)
         .toDF("ID", "neighbours")
         .join(aDataFrameWithProperties, "ID")
         .map{x => // this is where I am lost
         }
```

I don't think my approach is any right, because I join the properties of each vertex with the array of their neighbours, but still I don't know the values of the properties for the neighbours...

**EDIT**

Some data to help understand what I want to accomplish... say you build the graph as in this answer to [how to create EdgeRDD from data frame in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135288/how-to-create-edgerdd-from-data-frame-in-spark)

```
val sqlc : SQLContext = ???

case class Person(id: Long, country: String, age: Int)

val testPeople = Seq(
   Person(1, "Romania"    , 15),
   Person(2, "New Zealand", 30),
   Person(3, "Romania"    , 17),
   Person(4, "Iceland"    , 20),
   Person(5, "Romania"    , 40),
   Person(6, "Romania"    , 44),
   Person(7, "Romania"    , 45),
   Person(8, "Iceland"    , 21),
   Person(9, "Iceland"    , 22)
 )

 val people = sqlc.createDataFrame(testPeople)
 val peopleR = people
   .withColumnRenamed("id"     , "idR")
   .withColumnRenamed("country", "countryR")
   .withColumnRenamed("age"    , "ageR")

 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

 val relations = people.join(peopleR,
       (people("id") < peopleR("idR")) &&
         (people("country") === peopleR("countryR")) &&
         (abs(people("age") - peopleR("ageR")) < 5))

 import org.apache.spark.graphx._

 val edges = EdgeRDD.fromEdges(relations.map(row => Edge(
       row.getAs[Long]("id"), row.getAs[Long]("idR"), ())))

 val users = VertexRDD.apply(people.map(row => (row.getAs[Int]("id").toLong, row.getAs[Int]("id").toInt)))

 val graph = Graph(users, edges)
```

Then you have a data frame like:

```
case class Person(id:Long, gender:Int, income:Int)
val properties = Seq(
  Person(1, 0, 321),
  Person(2, 1, 212),
  Person(3, 0, 212),
  Person(4, 0, 122),
  Person(5, 1, 898),
  Person(6, 1, 212),
  Person(7, 1, 22),
  Person(8, 0, 8),
  Person(9, 0, 212)
)

val people = sqlc.createDataFrame(properties)
```

I'd like to compute, for each Vertex, what is the average sex and what is the average income of the neighbours, returned as a DataFrame

Comment: Any reason why you keep properties separated from the graph? And what exactly is the expected output here?

Comment: When I build the graph I have the nodes but I don't have properties yet... Can I "attach" the properties? the expected outcome is a DataFrame with an ID column and the one column for each of the properties

Comment: So you don't want a graph? It kind of sound like job for `aggregateMessages` not DataFrames. Anyway, could you show some data?

Comment: No I don't want a Graph back, if this is what you mean... I'll put some data in  the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you should use graph operators instead of converting everything to a `DataFrame` but something like this should do the trick:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{explode, avg}

val statsDF = graph.collectNeighbors(EdgeDirection.Either)
  .toDF("ID", "neighbours")
  // Flatten neighbours column
  .withColumn("neighbour", explode($"neighbours"))
  // and extract neighbour id
  .select($"ID".alias("this_id"), $"neighbour._1".alias("other_id"))
  // join with people 
  .join(people, people("ID") === $"other_id")
  .groupBy($"this_id")
  .agg(avg($"gender"), avg($"income"))
```

> what if instead of an average I'd like to count, say, the number of neighbours with gender = the gender of myself and then find the average over all connections

To do this you would need two separate joins - one on `this_id` and one on `ohter_id`. Next you can simply aggregate with following expression:

```
avg((this_gender === other_gender).cast("integer"))
```

Regarding graph operators there are a few operations you can use. For starters you can use join operation to add properties to vertices:

```
val properties: RDD[(VertexId, (Int, Int))] = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1L, (0, 321)), (2L, (1, 212)), (3L, (0, 212)),
  (4L, (0, 122)), (5L, (1, 898)), (6L, (1, 212)),
  (7L, (1, 22)), (8L, (0, 8)), (9L, (0, 212))
))

val graphWithProperties = graph
  .outerJoinVertices(properties)((_, _, prop) => prop)
  // For simplicity this assumes no missing values 
  .mapVertices((_, props) => props.get)
```

Next we can aggregate messages to create new `VertexRDD`

```
val neighboursAggregated = graphWithProperties
  .aggregateMessages[(Int, (Int, Int))](
    triplet => {
      triplet.sendToDst(1, triplet.srcAttr)
      triplet.sendToSrc(1, triplet.dstAttr)
    },
    {case ((cnt1, (age1, inc1)), (cnt2, (age2, inc2))) =>
      (cnt1 + cnt2, (age1 + age2, inc1 + inc2))}
  )
```

Finally it we can replace existing properties:

```
graphWithProperties.outerJoinVertices(neighboursAggregated)(
  (_, oldProps, newProps) => newProps match {
    case Some((cnt, (gender, inc))) => Some(
      if (oldProps._1 == 1) gender.toDouble / cnt
      else  1 - gender.toDouble / cnt,
      inc.toDouble / cnt
    )
    case _ => None
  })
```

If you're interested only into values you can pass all required values in `aggregateMessages` and omit the second `outerJoinVertices`.

Comment: the only problem I have is to understand how to add properties starting from a data frame and not an rdd... I can map the data frame to a VertexRDD[Long, Row] but then your code breaks...

Comment: Could you elaborate? One problem I've encountered is that `users` RDD from your example is incorrect.

Comment: nothing to elaborate, sorry... you wrote "aggregateMessgenders" and I copy&pasted it... :)

Comment: ok so I have tried a lot on that, but failed miserably... I don't understand the aggregateMessage thing... I don't have two values like (age2, inc2), but many more in my data frame... what I can pass  here is the entire row, but then the aggregate message is not working... can you add some comments to your code so that I understand better how aggregate message works?

Comment: I also have problems to use the first part of your new code because I have a data frame and not an rdd...

Comment: The first part shouldn't be problem. I admit that both `aggregateMessage` are and `(outer)JoinVertices` functions are kind of esoteric. I'll prepare some better explanation when I have some time.

Comment: I've posted complete explanation how to attach additional properties [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34556928/1560062).